# Flutter - Can't build apk. Execution failed for task ':app:minifyReleaseWithR8'

Tags: android, flutter, mobile

I'm trying to build the release apk of my project and stumbled on this error today:

R8: Type io.flutter.plugins.webviewflutter.GeneratedAndroidWebView$WebViewClientHostApiCodec is defined multiple times

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:minifyReleaseWithR8'.

> com.android.tools.r8.CompilationFailedException: Compilation failed to complete, origin: /flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/webview_pro_android-2.8.3+3/android/build/intermediates/runtime_library_classes_jar/release/classes.jar:io/flutter/plugins/webviewflutter/GeneratedAndroidWebView$WebViewClientHostApiCodec.class

This is related to the flutter_webview_pro plugin. I'm using the 3.0.1+3 version. I've tried to open an issue on the plugin's github page, but can't find the Issue tab. Is there a better alternative to this plugin? Can't use the official one because it doesn't support opening a file chooser on Android. Thanks for the attention in advance.

Comment: This link might help you out - https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/99479

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Mayur, but I checked and I don't have duplicated plugins on my project. It's inside the plugin itself. I'm switching to another one to reimplement my webview: https://github.com/pichillilorenzo/flutter_inappwebview. I'm going to close this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sadly I didn't find the answer to solve this problem and decided to use another plugin for the same purpose: https://github.com/pichillilorenzo/flutter_inappwebview

Answer (score 0):

I believe you were probably importing another package that this webview_pro also imports, maybe even the default webview_flutter